# What are square matrices of this form called?

Tags: matrices, notation, terminology, magic-square

Is there a name for square matrices whose rows and columns (and only these; indeed, the main diagonal entries always sum to $n \alpha,$ where $n$ is the size of the matrix, and $\alpha$ each entry of the form $a_{ii}$) sum to the same value?

For example, something like $$\begin{bmatrix}
2&1&0&1\\
1&2&1&0\\
0&1&2&1\\
1&0&1&2
\end{bmatrix}.$$

**PS.** As it might help, an additional property that these matrices have is that they are at least persymmetric (that is in addition to the constancy of the row/column-sum above), although the antidiagonal need not be constant.

Comment: Not exactly what you asked, but a matrix with constant diagonals like your example is called a Toeplitz matrix.

Comment: @Klaus I didn't know that. That would mean the matrices I am interested in are a subclass of Toeplitz matrices. It's some progress, if you ask me!

Comment: Maybe a "multiple of a doubly stochastic matrix"?

Comment: @TeddantheTerran What's a doubly stochastic matrix? Could you give an example too?

Comment: @Allawonder A doubly stochastic matrix is a square matrix of nonnegative real numbers with each row and column summing to 1. For example, the identity matrix.

Comment: oh sorry, I misread.

Comment: @TeddantheTerran The example I give above is not a doubly stochastic matrix, as defined by you, unless we break it down into a sum, and that's of course just a linear combo of elementary matrices.

Comment: @Allawonder No, but I meant that it is a multiple of a stochastic matrix: Divide all entries by 4, and call this matrix M. Then M is doubly stochastic, and 4M is your matrix.

Comment: @TeddantheTerran Oh, wow. I had completely misunderstood you. Indeed, unless I'm mistaken, I guess you've solved my problem. Many thanks.

Comment: No worries. Unfortunately I don't have a more catchy name for it, but I guess "multiple of a DSM" pretty much describes it.

Comment: @TeddantheTerran I don't have problems with compactness of the term. I wanted actually to find out if such matrices have been studied (as these matrices appeared very symmetric when I encountered them to have escaped study). The fact that they are trivially (just by scaling them down!) connected to bistochastic matrices solves my problem completely, since it opens up an avenue to search the literature. Before I did not know what to search for; now I have important key words. There's a lot of difference, I tell you. Cheers! :)